# Convert to key-value in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, key-value

Currently I have mongodb Database. Each document have field `data` which is key-value storage. 
I want to convert it to

```
data:[
    {'k': key1, v: value1},
    {'k': key2, v: value2},
    {'k': key3, v: value3}]
```

My current strycture is:

```
data:{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3}
```

So I can use search on keys (currently I'm using $exists but it's to slow and after converting I Could index data.k and use index for fast searching. 
What is the fastest way to do so. Now I'm using pymongo individually edit every document individually and saving it. But it's to slow. Is there native way to do my job?

Comment: Okay. Your going in the right direction but you are posing the question in reverse. Yes you want to go to a structure like you define. But you are not showing the structure you are coming from so someone can give you pointers. The short shrift though is to look at the [**Bulk**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations update support in your driver for language of choice.

Comment: Updated. my question is about structure of `update()`  Because I'm new with mongo and it seems really weird for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution based on @Disposer variant

```
db.data.find({'d':{$exists: true}}).forEach(function(item){
    d=new Array(); 
    for (var k in item.d){
        d.push({'k': k, 'v': item.d[k]}) 
    } 
    item.d = d;  
    db.item.save(item)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, its a working none atomic solution;

```
db.qs.find().forEach(function(item)
{       
    item.data = new Array();
    item.data.push({ k : 'key1', v : item.key1});
    item.data.push({ k : 'key2', v : item.key2});
    item.data.push({ k : 'key3', v : item.key3});

    delete item.key1;  
    delete item.key2;  
    delete item.key3;  

    db.qs.save(item);
})
```

Comment: okay, It will work, but for each record keys and values are different